# Xamarin forms iOS debug on iPhone from windows without cable

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Is it possible to debug a Xamarin forms application on an iPhone from a windows machine without having access to a usb cable and Mac machine?

All reading I have come across regarding iPhone debugging from windows requires a Mac Machine to enable wireless debugging in xCode through some means.

Comment: A Mac (w/ Xcode) is required for wired or wireless debugging

Answer (score 0):

To compile an ios app, you will need XCode running on a mac. If you don't own a mac, you can try using a cloud service,
Using a virtual machine should also be possible, and another way is to use [appcenter](https://appcenter.ms/) to build your app.

Here is a artcle about how to debug ios locally on visual studio with hot restart https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/ios-dev-no-mac/  but there are some limitations.